# Redirect-Spring -MVC - how redirect control to home page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/redirect", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect()
{
    return "redirect:onLogin";
}
```

how to redirect control back to home page? the above code for retrieving admin home page is not working.

Comment: `return "redirect:/"`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/redirect", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect(){
    return "redirect:/onLogin";
}
```

You can also pass parameters on redirect to show Login Failure messages, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/redirect", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect(){
    return "redirect:/onLogin?success=false";
}
```

And then in your `login.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:if test="${param.success eq false}">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Login Failed!</h4>
    </div>
</c:if>
```